# Link direto não funciona com wget no ubunto

Tags: ubuntu, wget

Eu estou tentando baixar direto desse link `https://punchsub.zlx.com.br/download-vip/6262326895623150684821353451533450406/shingeki-no-kyojin-2-7-mp4`, porem mesmo usando o comando `wget --user=usuario --password=senha https://punchsub.zlx.com.br/download-vip/6262326895623150684821353451533450406/shingeki-no-kyojin-2-7-mp4`
 ele simplesmente fica conectando infinito, mas quando baixo pelo navegador funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: tentou com o curl? curl -u usuario:senha [url]

Comment: \Quando uso dessa forma retorna `<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.10</center>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: No Ubuntu 16.04, wget funcionou, versão 1.17.1. O curl 7.47.7 funcionou do jeito que descreveu. Significa que o comando  para quando recebe o 302. Usando o curl fica ```curl -L -u usuario:senha url```. Usando o wget, fica ```wget --max-redirect 100 --user usuario --password senha url```

Comment: Parece que o seu wget tem algum problema para tratar o 1o redirect. Você é redirecionado para ```aliancaproject.com.br``` e eu sou redirecionado para ```vip-validation2.punchsub.net```

Comment: @lemoce e oque eu posso fazer quando a isso ??

Comment: boa pergunta. Poderia fazer um ```sudo apt-get build-dep wget````e recompilar o wget na versão mais nova. Eu tentaria isso. Mas pode ser algo do seu DNS. Pode tentar usar o DNS da google (8.8.4.4). Veja que tem várias respostas para o seu problema.

Comment: Retorna `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58749/discussion-between-lucas-carezia-and-lemoce).

Answer (score 2):

Parece que o seu wget está configurado por default com `--max-redirect 0`. Isso implica que não fará o redirect depois de um 301 e 302.

Para isso pode usar as opções `-L` do curl e `--max-redirect` do wget.

Usando o curl

```
curl -L -u usuario:senha [url]
```

Usando o wget

```
wget --max-redirect 100 --user usuario --password senha [url]
```

*** Editado

Mas, isso não responde a pergunta.

Comment: Usando o `wget`, fica assim infinitamente `Resolving punchsub.zlx.com.br (punchsub.zlx.com.br)... 104.24.27.118, 104.24.28.118
Connecting to punchsub.zlx.com.br (punchsub.zlx.com.br)|104.24.27.118|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.aliancaproject.com.br/ [following]
--2017-05-14 09:06:43--  http://www.aliancaproject.com.br/
Resolving www.aliancaproject.com.br (www.aliancaproject.com.br)... 2607:5300:60:969a::, 163.172.64.158
Connecting to www.aliancaproject.com.br (www.aliancaproject.com.br)|2607:5300:60:969a::|:80...`

Comment: na minha máquina, wget funciona. Tentou o curl?

Comment: Tentei, ele retorna todo código de um pagina.

Comment: ```Connecting to punchsub.zlx.com.br (punchsub.zlx.com.br)|104.24.27.118|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://vip-validation2.punchsub.net/vip/vipDlRedir_1.php?downNum=6262326&slug=shingeki-no-kyojin-2-7-mp4&t=e [following]163.172.214.124|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://st1.punchsub.net/mp4/PUNCH_Shingeki_no_Kyojin_2_-_07_MQ.mp4 [following]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Saving to: ‘shingeki-no-kyojin-2-7-mp4.3```

Comment: O wget também funcionou aqui! ótima resposta.+1